# TTS not able to play once uploaded to server

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, mobile-application

I'm developing text-to-speech using speech synthesis. The voice can be played or supported on the browser (Chrome). But when uploaded to the server to be viewed in the mobile app, it seems that text-to-speech could not even be played.

Is there any way to make it function even uploaded to the server? I'm really stuck because I'm very new to all these things.

[Img in mobile app:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTHnO.jpg)

Javascript code:

```
onload = function() {
        if ('speechSynthesis' in window) with(speechSynthesis) {


            var playEle = document.querySelector('#play');
            var pauseEle = document.querySelector('#pause');
            var stopEle = document.querySelector('#stop');
            var flag = false;

            playEle.addEventListener('click', onClickPlay);
            pauseEle.addEventListener('click', onClickPause);
            stopEle.addEventListener('click', onClickStop);

            function onClickPlay() {
                if(!flag){
                    flag = true;
                    utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(document.querySelector('article').textContent);
                    utterance.lang = 'zh-CN';
                    utterance.onend = function(){
                        flag = false; playEle.className = pauseEle.className = ''; stopEle.className = 'stopped';
                    };
                    playEle.className = 'played';
                    stopEle.className = '';
                    speak(utterance);
                }

                let r = setInterval(() => {
                    console.log(speechSynthesis.speaking);
                        if (!speechSynthesis.speaking) {
                            clearInterval(r);
                        } else {
                        speechSynthesis.resume();
                        }
                    }, 14000);

                 if (paused) { /* unpause/resume narration */
                    playEle.className = 'played';
                    pauseEle.className = '';
                    resume();
                } 
            }

            function onClickPause() {
                if(speaking && !paused){ /* pause narration */
                    pauseEle.className = 'paused';
                    playEle.className = '';
                    pause();
                }
            }

            function onClickStop() {
                if(speaking){ /* stop narration */
                    stopEle.className = 'stopped';
                    playEle.className = pauseEle.className = '';
                    flag = false;
                    cancel();

                }
            }

        }

        else { /* speech synthesis not supported */
            msg = document.createElement('h5');
            msg.textContent = "Detected no support for Speech Synthesis";
            msg.style.textAlign = 'center';
            msg.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            msg.style.color = 'white';
            msg.style.marginTop = msg.style.marginBottom = 0;
            document.body.insertBefore(msg, document.querySelector('div'));
        }

    }
```

[Full HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt5r2.png)

Comment: I see you have with(speechSynthesis) set. Note that this is not recommended: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Comment: Also, using 'onload' means that that large image must load before the javascript is run. DOMContentLoaded may be better here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: I made a basic html and it all works, so maybe you're trying to run it before the image has fully loaded? Otherwise please show your full html and javascript and specify what OS/browser combination doesn't work, thanks.

Comment: @Frazer I will show you the full file (above). The things are I tried to load in server for mobile app, but could not play the voice. When I'm using a browser such as Chrome, my voice can play out. The current mobile app is the Android version.

Comment: Well, I'm not typing all that out! And without a reproducible example I can't help. Are you sure the script is loading? If you add document.querySelector('article').textContent = "Hello"; before your final } does it change the page?